# Matching confusing logic with two arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array which provides Geo-restriction information from API, this is an array list of countries where content is being BLOCKED :

> Array ( [0] => GU [1] => PR [2] => CA [3] => VI [4] => US [5] => UM
>   [6] => AS [7] => MP [8] => DE )

Now, I have another array which stores country-wise proxy information like this :

```
$proxies['US'] = 'my_us_proxy_url;
$proxies['DE'] = 'my_de_proxy_url;
$proxies['UK'] = 'my_uk_proxy_url;
$proxies['NL'] = 'my_nl_proxy_url;
```

I want to get value of the proxy which will allow user to bypass the country restriction i.e. a  `$proxies[KEY]` value where `KEY` does not exist in the first array.

This is one of the snippet I tried but like everything else this is not the logic what is needed.

```
            $isBlocked = array_values;
            //print_r($isBlocked);
            if (in_array('US',$isBlocked))
            {
                echo 'US Blocked';
                foreach ($isBlocked as $value) {

                    if (!array_key_exists($value,$proxies)){
                        //Find first non blocked proxy and continue
                        echo "<br/>" . $value ;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: You will get nothing execpt syntax error if you run the code

Comment: Edited the code above with another variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$key => $value` structure in your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($proxies as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, $isBlocked)){
        //Find first non blocked proxy and continue
        echo "<br/>" . $value ;
    }
}
```

[**Demo!**](http://eval.in/59140)

Comment: Thanks, @Amal that worked (can only select as right answer after 10 minutes). This place is amazing I got the solution in less then 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

That will be:

```
$data = ['GU', 'PR', 'CA', 'VI', 'US', 'UM', 'AS', 'MP', 'DE '];
$proxies['US'] = 'my_us_proxy_url';
$proxies['DE'] = 'my_de_proxy_url';
$proxies['UK'] = 'my_uk_proxy_url';
$proxies['NL'] = 'my_nl_proxy_url';

$result = array_diff_key($proxies, array_flip($data));
```

Comment: @EikePierstorff actually, it's about using PHP 5.5 (for me). But most times I have to care about PHP version, which OP has.

Answer (score 0):

Get the key from the proxies array via [array_keys](https://www.php.net/array_keys). Get the difference to the other array via [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). With large arrays that might a tad less expensive than foreach-loops.

Comment: `array_diff` seems a smart approach. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Stacked, Alma Do's anwser is even better - same result, saves one function call.